# How can I use a custom class in a TreeSet?

Tags: java, treeset

If I was using a `Set` similar to this:

```
Set<node> s=new TreeSet<node>();

class node {

  private int x;
  private int y;

}
```

Would this be acceptable, and since it's a TreeSet, would it also sort it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not going to be able to sort it without you implementing `Comparable<Node>`, and it won't really be an appropriate for set operations until you override `equals()` and `hashCode()`. (You don't *have* to override `equals` and `hashCode` for `TreeSet` to work, but it would make sense to do so.)

Something like this:

```
final class Node implements Comparable<Node> {

  private final int x;
  private final int y;

  Node(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  @Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (!(other instanceof Node)) {
      return false;
    }
    Node otherNode = (Node) other;
    return x == otherNode.x && y == otherNode.y;
  }

  @Override public int hashCode() {
    return x * 31 + y * 17; // For example...
  }

  @Override public int compareTo(Node other) {
    // As of Java 7, this can be replaced with
    // return x != other.x ? Integer.compare(x, other.x) 
    //     : Integer.compare(y, other.y);

    if (x < other.x || (x == other.x && y < other.y)) {
      return -1;
    }
    return x == other.x && y == other.y ? 0 : 1;
  }
}
```

(Note that by convention the class name would be `Node`, not `node`.)

Comment: what is the reason of making it `final class`?

Comment: @medopal: Equality and other things become harder to implement correctly (when there even *is* an idea of correctness) when inheritance is involved. Likewise when I know there are no subclasses, I know it's immutable. Basically I subscribe to "design for inheritance or prohibit it".

Comment: or "depending on the use case" use guava or apache commons to avoid the branching in your code and the let the library implement the hashcode and equals method.

Comment: @Carlos: No, hence the sentence stating "You don't have to override equals and hashCode for TreeSet to work, but it would make sense to do so." I find it much easier to reason about code when comparable implementations *also* obey natural equality.

Comment: "Note that null is not an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null) should throw a NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns false." Drop the first if statement.

Comment: @since 1.7 `return x != other.x ? Integer.compare(x, other.x) : Integer.compare(y, other.y);`

Comment: @Tom: Thanks, removed the "if" check. Will add a comment for the Integer.compare (good to see that's finally there...)

Comment: @Jon what does `hashCode` do and why do I have to override it?

Comment: @SNpn: That's a far bigger question than can be answered easily in comments - I suggest you look at the documentation in java.lang.Object to start with, and then ask another question if it doesn't explain everything. *In this case* as TreeSet only cares about ordering, you don't have to do it - but you'd get odd results if you used a HashSet instead.

Comment: @Jon one more question, how come when I try to override the compareTo function it says it doesnt need to be overriden. Also just by overriding the equals operation, does that make the treeset's sorting ability work?

Comment: @SNpn: Using @Override for interface methods is a nice way of communicating that you're providing the implementation of a method originally declared elsewhere. It's not *necessary*, and in Java 5 it's not permitted IIRC, but in Java 6+ I still prefer it. And no, *just* overriding `equals` won't let TreeSet sort the values - how would it be able to tell which value should come before the other?

Answer (score 6):

Node needs to implement a Comparable or you need to pass a custom Comparator which can compare two Node objects. Also, any hash based collection relies on the object suitably overriding equals() and hashcode() method.

Comment: FYI, TreeSet is not hash-based.

Comment: @Bohemian yes you are right, TreeSet or TreeMap specifically doesn't use hashing.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify equals, hashCode and implement the Comparable interface

Comment: That's not actually correct. Just Comparable is enough. You *should* implement equals(), but the default Object.equals() and Object.hashcode() is sufficient to "work" - there's no "have to" about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code as for as acceptance is concerned. But for sorting `Node` class MUST implement comparable interface.