# Which collection for sorted unique dataset?

Tags: java, collections

I want to have a Collection with the following requirements:

1.) before inserting an element it checks if there is already a element with the same name, if there is, the element is not inserted

2.) after inserting, the collection is automatically sorted by the salary of the persons in the collection

I insert persons with name and salary as attributes.

Which collection does fit these requirements?

Comment: Nothing built-in, and no libraries I'm aware of.  The best solution I can think of is to maintain a `Set` of names and a separate `SortedSet` sorted by salary and then name.

Comment: I think this has already been asked on SO - have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416176/how-can-i-use-a-custom-class-in-a-treeset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TreeSet and implement Comparator to sort the needed proprty. See 
[this](http://java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/treeset/comparator-object/) sample.

To discard the duplicate entry, you need to return 0 value;

```
    public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) {
        if(e1.getName().equals(e2.getName())) {
            return 0;
        }else if(e1.getSalary() > e2.getSalary()){
            return 1;
        }else if(e1.getSalary() == e2.getSalary() && (e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName()) > 1)) {
             return 1; // if the salary is equal, sort it based on name.
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I've checked this example but I have found no possibillity for blocking entries with the same name. The ordering of the salary works with the MySalaryComp. It blocks entries with the same salary, but thats not what I want

Comment: You need to add a extra condition to return 0 value, if the entry is already there.

Comment: updated the answer to sort the elements based on second property

Answer (score 1):

What about a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) ?
You may need to use the [constructor with a Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet-java.util.Comparator-).

Answer (score 0):

Louis is wrong!

A SortedSet would be the perfect.
You only have to implement the Comparable interface and compare the salary of the people.

Answer (score 0):

it will be fine for the SortedSet, but don't forget to implements the interface COMPARABLE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TreeSet over a HashSet, but Person has to implement Comparable interface (int compareTo(Person o) method) and override equals and hashCode methods to check the identity/unique based only on name field.
First create Person and implement/overrride methods :

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

    public Person(String name, double salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Person() {
    }        

    private String name;
    private Double salary;    

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    } 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "name=" + name + ", salary=" + salary + '}';
    }        

    public int compareTo(Person o) {        
        return salary.compareTo(o.getSalary());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 53 * hash + (this.name != null ? this.name.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Person other = (Person) obj;
        if ((this.name == null) ? (other.name != null) : !this.name.equals(other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }            
}
```

then create a HashSet and fill it with Person elements. The set will contain only elements with unique name attribute, that's done by using only name field in equals and hashCode methods.
To keep collection sorted - create a TreeSet using parameterized constructor - new TreeSet(Collection coll) , you have collection already populated with unique elements, so the sorting will take place during TreeSet initialization.

Here is the rest of snippet

```
public class TestPerson {

    public static void main(String [] args){

    Person p1 = new Person("first", 1000);
    Person p2 = new Person("second", 2000);
    Person p3 = new Person("third", 3000);
    Person p4 = new Person("first", 4000);
    Person p5 = new Person("second", 5000);

    TreeSet<Person> personSet = new TreeSet<Person>();
    personSet.add(p1);
    personSet.add(p2);
    personSet.add(p3);
    personSet.add(p4);
    personSet.add(p5);
        for (Person person : personSet){                    
            System.out.println(" === person element sorted : "+person);
        }    

    HashSet<Person> personHashSet = new HashSet<Person>();
    personHashSet.add(p1);
    personHashSet.add(p2);
    personHashSet.add(p3);
    personHashSet.add(p4);
    personHashSet.add(p5);

    TreeSet<Person> treePersonSet  = new TreeSet<Person>(personHashSet);
        for (Person person : treePersonSet){                    
            System.out.println(" === person element: "+person);
        }    
    }
}
```